# which of these is faster way to redirect

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

there are a few ways to code a Response.Redirect in ASP.NET (v4.5), but which of them leads to faster redirection?

```
Response.Redirect("foo.aspx");
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("foo.aspx");
Response.End();
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("foo.aspx", false);
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("foo.aspx", false);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

thanks!

Comment: By fast you mean for the client or the server?  Redirect false stop executing current page on the server so it will be "faster" for the server (saving CPU cycles).

Comment: Any minuscule saving you make in processing time will be completely swamped by latencies in the web. Don't worry about it.

Comment: the second one doesn't execute the Response.End, so the first two would be faster because it would terminate the execution of the current page

Comment: `Response.Redirect("foo.aspx")` is equivalent to `Response.Redirect("foo.aspx", true)`. The documentation should explain the rest .. i.e. what does "end request" do?

Comment: Try timing it with the DateTime class.  I think you'll find that the difference approximates to zero but I'd love to know if you find otherwise.

Comment: im more interested in what other devs consider best practice and why, i suppose.